# Android App Crash at Startup on Sony Xperia E4 4G LTE but not on other devices

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I'm using Genexus Ev3 build 10.3.92797 U3 to generate an Android Application which runs well on several devices like Samsung, LG, Moto-G, Nexus, etc.

But on Sony Xperia E4 4G LTE crashes showing "Application has stopped unexpectedly" after splash screen logo. My app requires the following permissions:

> android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
>   android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
>   android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
>   android.permission.INTERNET
>   android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
>   android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
>   android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
>   com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES

Could it be a screen resolution issue ? This phone has 540 x 960 pixels (~234 ppi pixel density).

The main panel has an image variable on screen and 6 icons. When I remove them and generate a new app, it works but when I choose an option it crash again on the called panel.

Comment: Maybe this stack trace could help:

Comment: http://mail.inalambrik.com.ec/public/downloadfile.aspx?f=OA8kbIgmii4DOrR0s6qtH6PJ1l7dTa0hdisSzXQXWe9z%2f%2bJgWNeRdSnmoDEq6Pd3m7d4BXypb3I%3d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GeneXus X Evolution 3 Upgrade 5 includes a fix related with that error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.artech.controls.GxImageViewBase.hashCode
```

The Upgrade 5 will be released next week, but there is a [preview available](https://www.genexus.com/developers/DownloadCenter?en,,,3926).

Comment: Great, I will wait for the release. Meanwhile I have restricted downloads from Google Play for Sony Xperia Devices.